# How are cookies handled in loadDataWithBaseURL in WebView?

Tags: java, android, cookies, webview

I'm loading all pages with loadDataWithBaseURL.
Step 1: Login (page 1) sets the cookie with php.
Step 2: I check for cookie, and load logged in page. (page 2)
Step 3: Now on page 2 i check for cookie again with php, and redirect to page 1 if cookie is not set or has wrong data.

It seems between step 2 & 3, cookie data is lost because i get redirected back to login..
Here is some code:

```
// Load login page
String urlIn = "http://myurl.com";    
String out = new Scanner(new URL(urlIn).openStream(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", out, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);


// User logged in, check for cookie and load page 2    
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
String cookie = cookieManager.getCookie("http://myurl.com");    
if(cookie != null && cookie.length() > 0){    
    String urlIn = "http://myurl.com/user/";
    String out = new Scanner(new URL(urlIn).openStream(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", out, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect `loadDataWithBaseURL()` to ignore cookies, simply because there is no HTTP involved. Cookies are an HTTP construct, and `loadDataWithBaseURL()` gets the page directly from you, not from HTTP.

Cookies might be applied for HTTP requests for resources emanating from the content that is loaded (e.g., images).

Comment: I was beginning to suspect this. Looks like i must reevaluate my approach to loading local resources in WebView to maintain cookie data.